# Problems Using (AjaxControlToolkit)ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit and Telerik RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, scriptmanager, toolkit

I am using (AjaxControlToolkit)ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit which is an open-source project built on top of the Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX framework.

Also, I am using the Telerik RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX

In order to use the (AjaxControlToolkit)ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit, I have to declare the asp:ScriptManager  in my aspx page.

In order to use the Telerik RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX, I have to declare the telerik:RadScriptManager in my aspx page.

Sadly, I get the following error:

Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Could someone please tell me how I can use both technologies?

Thanks,

New

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the asp:scriptmanager as the telerik one is built on top of the asp one and will handle both technologies.

Comment: I've used the op's combination in a previous life and your answer is quite correct